# Не применяется значение Padding через Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml

Не применяется значение Padding через Style -> Setter

Если указать непосредственно самому элементу, то все работает

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource expanderTextBlockStyle}" Padding="10 0" ....
```

Много TextBlock элементов, поэтому применяю стили в таком виде:

```
<Style x:Key="expanderTextBlockStyle">
            <Setter Property="Control.Padding" Value="10 0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Control.FontWeight" Value="Normal"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Свойства FontSize и FontWeight работают , а Padding - нет!

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: [`Object--DispatcherObject--DependencyObject--Visual--UIElement--FrameworkElement--TextBlock`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock?view=netframework-4.7.2) - я не вижу в иерархии наследования класса Control, почему оно должно применяться?

Comment: @tym32167 наследуется ObjectDispatcher--ObjectDependency--ObjectVisual--UIElement--FrameworkElement-Control
namespace System.Windows.Controls - есть
Остальное же все работает

Comment: я так понимаю можно изменить через Template(ControlTemplate) ? 
Я еще изучаю) и не знаю всех тонкостей...

Comment: `TextBlock` не является наследником `Control`. Укажите в стиле `TargetType="TextBlock"` и устанавливайте сеттером просто `Property="Padding"`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TextBlock не является наследником Control. Укажите в стиле
>   TargetType="TextBlock" и устанавливайте сеттером просто
>   Property="Padding"